# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'property' and 'complex'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, отладка

Есть код, в котором проводится расчет центробежной форсунки ЖРД, каждая формула представляет собой отдельную функцию. Код имеет основной класс `Injector`, в котором проводятся все основные расчеты, а также два других `CentrifugalInjector` и `ScrewInjector`, в этих двух классах записаны вычисления, которые пользователю нужно выбрать перед началом расчетов, в зависимости от такого какой класс используется расчеты будут скорректированы.

Но после запуска кода получаем следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\LARIS\tests\test_centrifugal_injector.py", line 50, in <module>
    test()
  File "G:\LARIS\tests\test_centrifugal_injector.py", line 34, in test
    print(injector.equivalent_geometric_characteristic_injector)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "G:\LARIS\src\centrifugal_injector_calc.py", line 95, in equivalent_geometric_characteristic_injector
    return geometric_characteristics / (1 + self.coefficient_friction / 2 * self.radius_tangential_inlet *
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'property' and 'complex'
```

Код программы:

```
import math
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


class AngularValues(Enum):
    RIGHT_ANGLE = 90


class ConstructiveTypes(Enum):
    CENTRIFUGAL_INJECTOR = "CENTRIFUGAL"
    SCREW_INJECTOR = "SCREW"


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Injector:
    outer_diameter_injector: float
    side_wall_thickness_injector: float
    number_input_tangential_holes: float

    diameter_input_tangential_holes: float
    length_input_tangential_holes: float

    relative_length_twisting_chamber: float

    diameter_injector_nozzle: float
    relative_length_injector_nozzle: float

    angle_nozzle_axis: float

    mass_flow_rate: float
    viscosity: float

    injector_type: str

    @property
    def diameter_twisting_chamber_injector(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает диаметр камеры закручивания центробежной форсунки"""
        return self.outer_diameter_injector - 2 * self.side_wall_thickness_injector

    @property
    def relative_length_tangential_hole(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает отношение длины входного тангенциального к его диаметру"""
        return self.length_input_tangential_holes / self.diameter_input_tangential_holes

    @property
    def length_twisting_chamber(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает длину камеры закручивания центробежной форсунки"""
        return self.relative_length_twisting_chamber * self.diameter_twisting_chamber_injector

    @property
    def radius_twisting_chamber_injector(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает радиус камеры закручивания центробежной форсунки"""
        return self.diameter_twisting_chamber_injector / 2

    @property
    def radius_input_tangential_holes(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает радиус входных тангенциальных отверстий"""
        return self.diameter_input_tangential_holes / 2

    @property
    def radius_tangential_inlet(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает величину радиуса, на котором расположена ось входного тангенциального отверстия от оси форсунки"""
        return self.radius_twisting_chamber_injector - self.radius_input_tangential_holes

    @property
    def length_injector_nozzle(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает длину сопла форсунки"""
        return self.relative_length_injector_nozzle * self.diameter_injector_nozzle

    @property
    def radius_injector_nozzle(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает радиус сопла форсунки"""
        return self.diameter_injector_nozzle / 2

    @property
    def reynolds_number(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает число Рейнольдса"""
        return (4 * self.mass_flow_rate) / (math.pi * self.viscosity * self.diameter_input_tangential_holes
                                            * math.sqrt(self.number_input_tangential_holes))

    @property
    def coefficient_friction(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает коэффициент трения"""
        return 10 ** ((25.8 / (math.log(self.reynolds_number, 10))**2.58) - 2)

    @property
    def equivalent_geometric_characteristic_injector(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает эквивалентную геометрическую характеристику"""
        if self.injector_type == ConstructiveTypes.SCREW_INJECTOR.value:
            geometric_characteristics = ScrewInjector.geometric_characteristics_screw_injector
        elif self.injector_type == ConstructiveTypes.CENTRIFUGAL_INJECTOR.value:
            geometric_characteristics = CentrifugalInjector.geometric_characteristics_centrifugal_injector

        return geometric_characteristics / (1 + self.coefficient_friction / 2 * self.radius_tangential_inlet *
                                            (self.radius_tangential_inlet + self.diameter_input_tangential_holes -
                                             self.radius_injector_nozzle))


class ScrewInjector(Injector):
    cross_sectional_area_one_passage_channel: float

    @property
    def geometric_characteristics_screw_injector(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает геометрическую характеристику шнековой форсунки"""
        return (math.pi * self.radius_tangential_inlet * self.radius_injector_nozzle) / \
               (self.number_input_tangential_holes * self.cross_sectional_area_one_passage_channel)


class CentrifugalInjector(Injector):
    @property
    def geometric_characteristics_centrifugal_injector(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает геометрическую характеристику центробежной форсунки"""
        if self.angle_nozzle_axis == AngularValues.RIGHT_ANGLE.value:
            return (self.radius_tangential_inlet * self.radius_injector_nozzle) / \
                   (self.number_input_tangential_holes * self.radius_input_tangential_holes**2)
        else:
            return (self.radius_tangential_inlet * self.radius_injector_nozzle) / \
                   (self.number_input_tangential_holes * self.radius_input_tangential_holes**2) * self.angle_nozzle_axis
```

Код файла проверки:

```
from src.centrifugal_injector_calc import Injector, CentrifugalInjector, ScrewInjector


def test() -> None:
    common = {
        "outer_diameter_injector": 8,
        "side_wall_thickness_injector": 1,
        "number_input_tangential_holes": 10,
        "diameter_input_tangential_holes": 10,
        "length_input_tangential_holes": 10,
        "relative_length_twisting_chamber": 10,
        "diameter_injector_nozzle": 10,
        "relative_length_injector_nozzle": 10,
        "angle_nozzle_axis": 10,
        "mass_flow_rate": 10,
        "viscosity": 1,
        "injector_type": "CENTRIFUGAL"
    }

    injector = Injector(
        **common
    )

    print(injector.diameter_twisting_chamber_injector)
    print(injector.relative_length_tangential_hole)
    print(injector.length_twisting_chamber)
    print(injector.radius_twisting_chamber_injector)
    print(injector.radius_input_tangential_holes)
    print(injector.radius_tangential_inlet)
    print(injector.length_injector_nozzle)
    print(injector.radius_injector_nozzle)
    print(injector.reynolds_number)
    print(injector.coefficient_friction)
    print(injector.equivalent_geometric_characteristic_injector)

    centrifugal = CentrifugalInjector(
        **common
    )

    print(centrifugal.geometric_characteristics_centrifugal_injector)

    screw = ScrewInjector(
        **common, cross_sectional_area_one_passage_channel=5.0
    )

    print(screw.geometric_characteristics_screw_injector)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Как решить данную проблему? Книга в которой записаны формулы для расчета (нужные 47 - 54): [Расчет смесеобразования ЖРД](http://repo.ssau.ru/bitstream/Uchebnye-izdaniya/Raschet-i-proektirovanie-smeseobrazovaniya-v-kamere-ZhRD-Elektronnyi-resurs-ucheb-posobie-78330/1/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%92.%D0%A1%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%96%D0%A0%D0%94%202008.pdf?ysclid=lu86mdpxkd492907540)

**UPD:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\LARIS\tests\test_centrifugal_injector.py", line 50, in <module>
    test()
  File "G:\LARIS\tests\test_centrifugal_injector.py", line 34, in test
    print(injector.equivalent_geometric_characteristic_injector)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя вызывать свойства, использующие состояние класса `self` просто от базовых классов, не от экземпляров класса.

Вообще используйте лучше перегрузку - определяйте в разных классах-наследниках разные по содержанию свойства с **одинаковым** названием. Тогда не нужно будет проверять, что за класс у вас, просто сразу вызовется метод от того класса, который сейчас имеет место быть:

```py
class Injector:
...
    @property
    def equivalent_geometric_characteristic_injector(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает эквивалентную геометрическую характеристику"""
        return self.geometric_characteristics / (1 + self.coefficient_friction / 2 * self.radius_tangential_inlet *
                                            (self.radius_tangential_inlet + self.diameter_input_tangential_holes -
                                             self.radius_injector_nozzle))

...

class ScrewInjector(Injector):
    cross_sectional_area_one_passage_channel: float

    @property
    def geometric_characteristics(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает геометрическую характеристику шнековой форсунки"""
        return (math.pi * self.radius_tangential_inlet * self.radius_injector_nozzle) / \
               (self.number_input_tangential_holes * self.cross_sectional_area_one_passage_channel)


class CentrifugalInjector(Injector):
    @property
    def geometric_characteristics(self) -> float:
        """Возвращает геометрическую характеристику центробежной форсунки"""
        if self.angle_nozzle_axis == AngularValues.RIGHT_ANGLE.value:
            return (self.radius_tangential_inlet * self.radius_injector_nozzle) / \
                   (self.number_input_tangential_holes * self.radius_input_tangential_holes**2)
        else:
            return (self.radius_tangential_inlet * self.radius_injector_nozzle) / \
                   (self.number_input_tangential_holes * self.radius_input_tangential_holes**2) * self.angle_nozzle_axis
```

Потом у вас правда вылезет другая проблема - с тем, что вы не задали значение переменной класса `ScrewInjector.cross_sectional_area_one_passage_channel`.

Comment: изменил код как вы подписали и задал переменную в класс ScrewInjector. но вылезает другая ошибка, описал в вопросе